# Dynamic routing in angularjs using single html page?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm working with an application in angular where I have items in an array, and when I click on each item, details should be displayed in details page,I want to achieve this by displaying details of all items in the same details page dynamically, how do I do this? 
Here is my code

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mobileController">
search:<p><inpu type="text" ng-model="test"></p>  
<ul>  
 <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter :test" >
  <a href=#/> {{ x }}</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
     <div ng-view></div>

     var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller('mobileController', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ['iphone', 'Moto', 'Oneplus'];
    });
    </body>
```

I want to display the details of iPhone ,moto,oneplus in same details page,when user clicks on iPhone iPhone details should be displayed and same for others.

Comment: Please share yours existing code which you have tried

Comment: Thank you!can you please look into the edited code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OciJ50TetG7zt7tS0OAR?p=preview) on how to do what you want using UI-Router

You can use two states to do what you want by having two states: one for the list view and one for the details view.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('items', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'ItemsListCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'items-list.html',
    resolve: {
      Items: function (ItemsService) {
        return ItemsService.getAll();
      }
    }
  })
  .state('items.details', {
    url: ':itemId/',
    controller: 'ItemDetailsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'item-details.html',
    resolve: {
      Item: function (ItemsService, $stateParams) {
        return ItemsService.getById($stateParams.itemId);
      }
    }
  })
```

When someone clicks on an item you send them to a url with the itemId as a stateParam and resolve that item as you load the view within the view you have currently rendered (these are called nested/child views in ui-router).

Then in the controllers you just inject the items/item you resolved at the state level, and can manipulate them or assign them to your scope.

```
  .controller('ItemsListCtrl', function ($scope, Items, $state) {
    $scope.Items = Items;

    $scope.viewItemDetails = function (item) {
      $state.go('items.details', {itemId: item.id});
    };
  })
  .controller('ItemDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, Item, $state) {
    console.log(Item);
    $scope.Item = Item;

    $scope.closeDetails = function () {
      $state.go('items');
    };
  })
```

I'd recommend checking out UI-Router's docs https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki